# Qt5 - static libraries with static CRT

Tags: qt5, nmake

I'm trying to build Qt5.0.2 (MSVC10, Win7) statically, with static CRT.

I've modified `Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\Src\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010\qmake.conf` replacing every occurrence of `MD` and `MDd` compiler flags with `MT` and `MTd` respectively. Then I configure Qt: `configure -debug-and-release -static -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests`.

`Configure` detects the platform correctly: `QMAKESPEC...win32-msvc2010 (detected)`

However, it seems that the above modifications have no effect: when I run `nmake`, `cl` gets invoked with `-MD` flag.

How can I trace/debug this issue?

**UPDATE:** I've noticed, that the library makefiles (qtbase/src/corelib/Makefile.Release, etc) do not get updated, so they keep containing `MD` option. How to make them updated?